# handling data returned from SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have had a lot of trouble Taking my results from a query and then manipulating it, as it comes to back in the form of an object. in a project I'm working on i have been taking results from queries and putting them into combo boxes and text boxes. however now I'm at a point where i need to perform an equation with my returned object Before i load it into a text box.

```
using (data1 ds = new data1())
{
    DataTable dt = ds.dataset.Tables[0];
    List<string> coolList = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        coolList.Add(row[0].ToString());
    }
}
using (data2 ds = new data2())
{
    DataTable dt = ds.dataset.Tables[0];
    List<string> coolList = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        coolList.Add(row[0].ToString());
    }
}
string cat;
cat = txtbox1.SelectedText;
```

What i need to do is this.

```
double answer = data1 * ((cat/data2)^2.333)
```

if answer <3 
then answer = 3

the selected items from the queries will always be a single double, the selected text will also be a double.

then textbox2.text = answer

Comment: Use the IF statement you posted. You pretty much already answered this.

Comment: @SeanLange my issue is converting the data i get from my table into a form that i can use to accomplish this equation.

Comment: To get a number from a string use `Parse` (or `TryParse`) with the datatype you want to convert to - e.g. `string textnumber = "4323"; int numericNumber = Int32.Parse(textNumber);`